# Ошибка: TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, сериализация

Получаю ошибку в строке `json.dumps(data) if dump else data`:

```
def JsonResponse(data, dump=True, status=None):
    status = status or httplib.OK

    if 'errors' in data:
        data['success'] = False

    elif 'code' in data:
        data['success'] = False

    elif 'success' not in data:
        data['success'] = True

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(data) if dump else data,
        content_type=JSON_MIMETYPE,
        status=status,
    )
```

Код выше вызывается через этот декоратор:

```
def wrap_json(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def _wrap_json(request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            response = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return lib_http.JsonResponseBadRequest(
                json.loads(e.message),
                lib_errors.BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            log.exception(str(e) or 'wrap_json', request=request)

            return lib_http.JsonInternalServerError("Internal Server Error. Try again later.")

        if shouldnt_handle(response):
            return response

        return lib_http.JsonResponse(response)

    return _wrap_json
```

Получаю ошибку

> TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Comment: можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: https://code-maven.com/serialize-datetime-object-as-json-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что среди сериализуемых данных могут быть объекты типа, что не будет имеет маппинга от питоничьего типа (такой как `datetime`) к типу [json](/questions/tagged/json). Вообще, у JSON нет типа даты. Если нужно дату поместить, то используется строка или как число (т.е. `timestamp`)

Как вариант, нужно самому задать в функцию `json.dumps` обработчик типов для конвертации.

[Попробуйте так:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875813/5909792)

```
import datetime

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()

...

def JsonResponse(data, dump=True, status=None):
    status = status or httplib.OK

    if 'errors' in data:
        data['success'] = False

    elif 'code' in data:
        data['success'] = False

    elif 'success' not in data:
        data['success'] = True

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(data, default=default) if dump else data,
        #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        content_type=JSON_MIMETYPE,
        status=status,
    )
```